# Changing from Php4 to Php5

Tags: php, prestashop

I submitted a Php script to Prestashop and they asked me to convert it from php4 to Php5. Any conversion tools out there?

Comment: @bazmegakapa: ;-) I meant a script anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> I submitted a Php script to Prestashop and they asked me to convert it from php4 to Php5. Any conversion tools out there? thanks.

None that I know of. Just install PHP 5 (a bit late though!) and run the script(s) to see if there are any errors. You might want to read [the PHP documentation on migrating](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php) from 4 to 5 though, as there are a few things that broke backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. Form the reading, my code is basic has no changes in php5.

Answer (score 1):

[The PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php) (migration notes).

(Somewhat) seriously though, turn on your errors (`error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`) and see what doesn't work.

If you are pre-php 4.2, you should be aware that `register_globals` is now **disabled** by default

Comment: You *forgot* `E_STRICT` for `error_reporting`. As for `register_globals`, they will be gone completely in PHP 5.4 (Alpha 1 already available).